# kotlin google map api

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

l am junior in kotlin and i try to show latitude and longitude for specific airport on google map . using Async Task to get data json for latitude and longitude for airport then intent coordinates in google maps . but when l am try to intent the code inside google map code l got red line under coordinatesText intent .

```
  override fun onMapReady(p0: GoogleMap?) {
        val sydney = LatLng(coordinatesText)
        p0!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        p0.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
```

main activity class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {


    lateinit var mapFragment : SupportMapFragment
    lateinit var googleMap: GoogleMap
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val url = "xxxxx/airport.json?code=BGW"
        Download().execute(url)
        mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this@MainActivity)

    }

    override fun onMapReady(p0: GoogleMap?) {
        val sydney = LatLng(coordinatesText)
        p0!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        p0.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
    //    full class for json api
    inner class Download : AsyncTask<String,String,String>(){

        override fun onPreExecute() {
        }
        //        for build connection
        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String{

            try {

                val url = URL(p0[0])
                val urlConnect = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                urlConnect.connectTimeout = 700
                val inputStream = urlConnect.inputStream
                val dataJsonAsStr = covertStreamToString(urlConnect.inputStream)
                publishProgress(dataJsonAsStr)

            }   catch (e: Exception){

            }
            return ""
        }

        //        for get items from json api
        override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?) {

            val json= JSONObject(values[0])
            val result = json.getJSONObject("result")
            val response =result.getJSONObject("response")
            val airport =response.getJSONObject("airport")
            val pluginData =airport.getJSONObject("pluginData")
            val details =pluginData.getJSONObject("details")
            val position =details.getJSONObject("position")
            val latitude =position.getString("latitude")

            coordinatesText.setText(latitude)

        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {

        }

    }

    //    for connection api
    fun covertStreamToString (inputStream: InputStream): String {

        val bufferReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
        var line:String
        var  allString:String=""
        try {
            do{
                line=bufferReader.readLine()
                if (line!=null)
                    allString+=line
            }while (line!=null)

            bufferReader.close()
        }catch (ex:java.lang.Exception){}

        return allString;
    }

    //    full class for json api


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is "l got red line under coordinatesText". In the code you added to your question, coordinatesText is used twice: in functions onMapReady and onProgressUpdate. Do you get a red line in both functions or only in onMapReady?

The LatLng class has [one constructor](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng#public-constructor-summary) that expects two double parameters. It seems like you are giving it a single String parameter (that is equal to the latitude from the JSON position, that you extracted in function onProgressUpdate).

To test this idea, you could try replacing

```
val sydney = LatLng(coordinatesText)
```

with something like

```
val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
```

Comment: you are answer does not related to my question